# Setting Data to TinyMCE Editor

Tags: php, tinymce, wysiwyg, html-entities

I have my textbox value set to its data using `htmlentities` like:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities('...');?>" />
```

The same I did for textarea:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities('...');?></textarea>
```

It works fine until I convert the textarea to TinyMCE editor...

When I convert the textarea to TinyMCE editor all the things get crappy and shows the encoded html codes in text editor.

So what can be done to set encoded html data in TinyMCE?

Comment: well i used mysql_escape_string and my data are stores all html chars as it is ... like: <script>alert('hell');</script> too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `htmlentities()` inside the editor.

Comment: tinyMCE is rendering your html content. If you convert it using html entities it will be displayed as it is. for example ' < ' will be displayed as ' &lt;'

Comment: LOL, i asked almost the same as a comment but this one is accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Example from [TinyMCE docs](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_TinyMCE_in_PHP):

```
$sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['elm1']),$allowedTags);
...
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80"><?php echo $sContent;?></textarea>
```